# Will I get the trophy if I defeat the ender dragon on peaceful?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing Minecraft PS3 (Legacy Console) on Peaceful difficulty, and I'm about to go into The End. If I defeat the Ender Dragon on Peaceful, will I still get the trophy?

Comment: Unless it says "Defeat the Ender Dragon on X difficulty" then there is no reason you wouldn't get it for being on Peaceful.

Comment: @Mkalafut Wouldn't peaceful cause him to despawn?

Comment: @peper757 I think you're right actually.  I just now recalled that on top of HP regeneration and no hunger loss, there aren't even monsters..  I'm sure someone with more knowledge will come in and answer this one.  I'm not here to steal rep I was just giving my 2 cents, which appear to be wrong anyway.

Comment: Well, my first answer was wrong, and I can't actually answer the question, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will, I tried it myself and got it. It only doesn't work when you're in creative mode of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ender dragon on peaceful because there is no mobs not including animals so you must be on easy or above.

Comment: Are you sure of this, the comment above states otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can get the trophy in peaceful mode, and the ender dragon does spawn in peaceful because it's a boss and not a mob.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the trophy on any difficulty, and you will even get the trophy when you defeat the Ender Dragon in Creative Mode.

Comment: Other answers can object to yours. Please provide evidence with your answer to justify your statements.